# Block in reference root not loaded but loaded in reference header

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, phtml, custom-template

> Magento CE 1.9.4.5

I created a module and successfully had it loaded. The xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="mymodule.topbar" template="topbar/content.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

As you can see, the content is the `reference name="header"` in `topbar/content.phtml` is loaded by calling `$this->getChildHtml('mymodule.topbar')` in `header.phtml`.

I wonder if I still need to load the topbar even when header is not used, so changed the xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" name="mymodule.topbar" template="page/html/topbar.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

I copied the `content.phml` file to `app/design/frontend/mymodule/mytheme/template/page/html` and renamed it to `topbar.phtml`. It suddenly doesn't load anymore and I can't see anything wrong.

Any one please give me some advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you update your page layouts to now call that block?

You’ve moved the block out of the “header” template’s scope. This means your block is no longer a child of header. So the old call to getChildHtml will be empty because your block isn’t a child of “header” in the layout XML. You need to now update the root templates to call your block.

Comment: Thanks. You are absolutely right. I was still using getChildHtml inside the header.phtml.